# Separate multiple variables in same column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataset that looks as following:

| Date | Time | Variable | Unit | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:00 | Freq | Mhz | 10 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:10 | Freq | Mhz | 13 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:20 | Freq | Mhz | 12 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:30 | Freq | Mhz | 15 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:40 | Freq | Mhz | 11 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:50 | Freq | Mhz | 13 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:01:00 | Freq | Mhz | 11 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:00 | Distance | m | 102 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:20 | Distance | m | 107 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:30 | Distance | m | 110 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:40 | Distance | m | 108 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:00:50 | Distance | m | 104 |
| 05-02-2021 | 10:01:00 | Distance | m | 107 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc | etc |

So I have the variables and its corresponding units are in the same column, however I would like them formatted differently. The time interval at which the different variables (Mhz, Distance) are measured is the same (every 10 seconds), although I would like an option independent of this.

I would like my data to look like the following, so it is easier to work with:

| DateTime | Frequency-Mhz | Distance-m |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-02-2021 10:00:00 | 10 | 102 |
| 05-02-2021 10:00:10 | 13 | 107 |
| 05-02-2021 10:00:20 | 12 | 110 |
| 05-02-2021 10:00:30 | 15 | 108 |
| 05-02-2021 10:00:40 | 11 | 104 |
| 05-02-2021 10:00:50 | 13 | 102 |
| 05-02-2021 10:01:00 | 11 | 107 |

So far, I have tried various solutions with pd.pitvot_tables, but to no avail. I get close to the solution but not quite yet. I have also tried solutions with .melt or .groupby to built a entire new dataframe, but these are failed.

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + " " + df['Time'])
df.pivot_table(index=['datetime'], columns='Variable', values='Value')
```

Comment: `10:00:60` is typo?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, need join columns and then convert `Value` to numeric, if not matched return NaNs:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + " " + df['Time'])
df['Variable'] = df['Variable'] + "-" + df['Unit']

df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'], errors='coerce')

df.pivot(index='datetime', columns='Variable', values='Value')
```

If possible duplication in `datetime` with `Variable` use:

```
df.pivot_table(index='datetime', columns='Variable', values='Value')
```